# help in designing a database for medical clinic keeping record of patient visit

Tags: database-design, schema, orm

I am making software for patients record keeping in a clinic . I have written a peewee model for setting up tables to store record of each patient visit and patient contact and a relative table that store name of parent or husband (in case female patient is married)

```
import peewee
from app.datastore.core import db as _db


class Patient(peewee.Model):
    """ Patinets table """

    name = peewee.CharField(max_length=90)
    townCity = peewee.CharField(max_length=200)
    contactnumber = peewee.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = peewee.IntegerField(default=0)
    gender = peewee.CharField(max_length=9)
    email = peewee.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
    postalAddress = peewee.TextField() 

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Patient Id: {}>".format(self.id)

    class Meta:
        database = _db

class Relative(peewee.Model):
    """ Visit attendence """

    patient = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Patient,
        related_name="patient")
    relation = peewee.CharField(max_length=10)
    relativeName = peewee.CharField(max_length=90)

    class Meta:
        database = _db

# the below table continues to increment on each visit of new or old patient by frontdesk.

class PatientAttendOnVisit(peewee.Model):
    """ Attendence or visit record """
    patient = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Patient, 
        related_name="patient")
    dateTimeofvisit = peewee.DateTimeField()
    attendtype = peewee.CharField(max_length=12) # walkin or appointment
    department = peewee.CharField(max_length=9) # medicine or dental

    class Meta:
        database = _db

# the below table continues to increment on each patient visit by doctor

class PatientCheckup(peewee.Model):
    """ 
    Patient Checkup table stores what patient reports on each visit 
    to doctor like symptoms, diagnosis and presciption
    """
    patient = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Patient, 
        related_name="patient")
    chiefcomplaint = peewee.TextField()
    symptoms = peewee.TextField()
    diagnosis = peewee.TextField()
    treatment = peewee.TextField()
    presciption = peewee.TextField()
    dateTimeofvisit = peewee.ForeignKeyField(PatientAttendOnVisit)

    class Meta:
        database = _db
```

[image]

I am very new to database driven application with no knowledge of db design
please help me design the best database and schema ?

Comment: Hi Ciasto. It will be easier for us to help you by drawing the relationships in an ERD instead of dumping code.

Comment: @RandolphWest I have added ERD..